# How to configure X11 for multiple monitors with different refresh rates?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, multiple-monitors, 19.04

I'm using Kubuntu 19.04, with `kscreen` removed, and I currently have my `xorg.conf` file as follows:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath        "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "GBT AORUS AD27QD"
    HorizSync       222.0 - 222.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 144.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS PB278"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 99.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 144.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-4: 2560x1440_144 +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, DP-2: 2560x1440_60 +2560+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

However, this doesn't seem to actually give me 144Hz on my primary monitor. Scrolling in Firefox is very clearly still 60Hz, and the rest of the OS similarly doesn't seem to be 144Hz, even though `xrandr` reports 144Hz (I think what's actually happening is that my mouse is running at 144Hz, but everything else is running at 60Hz):

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
[...]
DP-2 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
[...]
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 609mm x 355mm
   2560x1440     59.95 + 143.97*  120.00  
[...]
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If I remove the second monitor (i.e. the PB278) from the config file, such that it is fully disabled, my primary monitor does run at 144Hz.

How do I configure my `xorg.conf` file such that I can use both monitors at the same time, running my primary display at 144Hz and my secondary at 60Hz?